# How do I map <cmd>-<shift>-f to run Ack plugin in Vim?

Tags: macos, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, ack

I'm new to vim and I'm trying to map a key combo for running the Ack plugin found here: https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim

I want to map `cmd-shift-f` to run the Ack command `:Ack`. I've added the following to `~/.vimrc`

```
nmap <D-F> :Ack<space>
```

It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using vim 7.3 within iTerm 2 on MacOS X.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that within <...> notation mappings, case is (mostly) insensitive, so you have to explicitly state you want to map with the shift key. Try this:

```
nmap <D-S-F> :Ack<space>
```

Comment: That still doesn't work. It's weird because nmap <C-F> :Ack<space> works for <ctrl><shift>-f. But it doesn't work with <cmd>

Comment: Hmm, interesting. `nmap <D-F> :Ack<space>` does work in MacVim, but not in the terminal. Looks like `cmd` is not recognised in a terminal.

Comment: And finally, according to this page: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29665/in-vim-how-to-map-command-right-and-command-left-to-beginning-of-line-and-e

You can only use `<cmd>` key mappings in a GUI Vim such as MacVim. I've decided to just go with `<ctrl>-f` for now.

Answer (score 3):

Or.. you could think about doing it this way:

`nmap <D-F> :Ack <space>`

You don't need to mention the shift & this still only triggers with a capital F (so although shift isn't mentioned in the binding, you still have to press it).

This works for me at least.

Comment: Worked for me! My use case: `nnoremap <silent> <D-D> <C-w>s`