# Can I use the `<cmd>` key in terminal Vim at all?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, vim, iterm2

Following on from my other recent question:
[How do I map <cmd>-<shift>-f to run Ack plugin in Vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/387207/how-do-i-map-cmd-shift-f-to-run-ack-plugin-in-vim)

Is is possible to use the `<cmd>` key in Vim at all?

If Vim doesn't recognise the key, is it possible to remap the key outside of Vim (somehow?) to something else and map *that* key within Vim?

I'm using iTerm 2 on Lion with Vim 7.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`<D->` only works in MacVim.

A quick google will return a bunch of hacks and third party solutions. All the solutions I know either work system-wide or are application-specific: if you remap `Cmd` in iTerm2 only, how are you going to open a new window or a new tab? With… with… the… **MOUSE?**

I can't imagine a good reason to remap the `Cmd` key to anything on a Mac. That would be insane.

Vim is not TextMate or whatever other editor you have used before. There is no way to transfer all your old habits seamlessly, point blank.

Instead of wasting your time trying to make Vim *and* your terminal into something that it's not and can't be you should learn how to use and customize Vim wisely. All your `Cmd`+`Shift`+`Ctrl`+`Alt` combos won't lead you anywhere. Especially in a terminal where `Alt` is often problematic and `Cmd` unusable.

Consider using `<leader>` (`:help leader`):

- it's portable on every platform
- it's less prone to conflicts with your OS or terminal emulator
- it opens a lot of easy to remember possibilities

Comment: Haha, thank you grawity, it's much cleaner now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had heard of the `<leader>` but I wasn't sure how it should be used. I agree with your point about portability, this is part of the reason I am moving to Vim. Thanks.

Comment: You can remap `Cmd` to `Control` in iTerm2, and then in the same window, add shortcuts to open a new tab with `^t`, etc. Then everything works!

Answer (score 9):

I found that iterm2 has an option in the keyboard settings to do this kind of thing. For ex below I mapped command-enter to be :wq

[image][image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution. This is just what i was looking for. I know about <Leader>, but i think that some things like saving a file should be universal.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Was looking all over for how to map `enter` and it's `\n`

Answer (score 6):

For simple commands there is a solution via sending the appropriate hex code to the terminal. For instance, I wanted to save in vim by pressing `cmd-s`. I mapped `cmd-s` in iterm2 to send the hex code `0x13` which is the code for `ctrl-s`, then I mapped `ctrl-s` to `:wq` in vim.

Comment: How exactly do you do such a thing? Thanks.

Comment: Did not work for me the 0x13 hex code :/
https://imgur.com/RjxOoLY

Comment: For the how to do this, see the pics below - thanks @jhickner for the idea to look at iTerm2

Answer (score 6):

The 2016 solution is to use [Karabiner](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner) open-source program which allows you to remap modifier and other keys with **very fine granularity**, for example

- Remap only the **left** <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> or <kbd>Option</kbd> key.
- Remap a key only for specific applications, e.g. only inside Terminal, Emacs, or virtual machine.

For example, here's how to remap left <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> key to act as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **only inside Terminal** (and leave the right one unaffected so that you could still use e.g. <kbd>⌘ Cmd + Tab</kbd> to switch between apps):

[image: karabiner-screenshot]

Comment: Awesome. Now I can use that in Vim properly, though (left) command+tab doesn't "alt tab". I can use right command but is there anyway to keep that somehow?